# Arrange SPAN and DIV with float left CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to arrange my span inside to a div with float left but when I put float left in the CSS seems that the spans are not inside to the div anymore.

I'm trying to explain with an image:

[image]

This is the code that I tried to write:

HTML

```
    <div class="block1">
        <div class="head-block-1">
            Best Selling Tickets
        </div>
        <div class="content-block-1">
            <div>
                <span class="data-block-1">
                    <img src="/nutickets2/images/circle.png" height="55px">
                </span>
                <span class="data-block-1">
                    <span>Adult - General</span><span><br>TEST TEST</span>
                </span>
                <span class="data-block-1">
                    <span>50 sold since Jan 17</span><span><br>20% more sold than last period</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.block1 {
    width: 96%;
    height: 96%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #d1d1d1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.head-block-1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.content-block-1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    padding: 15px;
}

.data-block-1 {
    width: 33%; 
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class for the "data-block1" is 33%, equal for each "span".  So, if you want to get the second "span" closer to left, you need to change the width of the left "span".
I've changed the "span" to "divs", because "span" is used when you need inline elements and "div" is used when you need a block element.

https://jsfiddle.net/scorpio777/rd9sqwuo/10/

```
<style>
.block1 {
    width: 96%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #d1d1d1;
   /* margin-bottom: 25px;*/
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.head-block-1 {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.content-block-1 {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height:55px;
}

.data-block-left {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.data-block-middle {
    width: 45%; 
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.data-block-right {
    width: 45%; 
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
span {display:block;}
</style>

<div class="block1">
      <div class="head-block-1">
         Best Selling Tickets
      </div>
      <div class="content-block-1">
          <div class="data-block-left">
              <img src="/nutickets2/images/circle.png">
          </div>
          <div class="data-block-middle">
              <span>
              Adult - General<br>
              TEST TEST</span>
          </div>
          <div class="data-block-right">
               <span>
               50 sold since Jan 17 <br>
               20% more sold than last period
               </span>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to make this code responsive for the mobile, do I have to modify the display property? Because now it is not responsive, the element cross over in the mobile.

Comment: If it's not responsive, it's something else.

Comment: You have to add @media query in your css for mobile and arrange the css sizes, fonts, widths, heights display settings for specific resolutions. You might have to make changes when your design is no longer right for tablet, ipad, mobile view. If you set the widths in percents it has to be ok, but maybe you must resize the fonts, graphics or other elements. In jsfinddle sample, if the left bottom window is resized it looks ok until small resolutions. Do you have the "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">" on the top of your page?

Comment: But is it possible to put the 3 divs stacked in the mobile version? Put the div in vertical and not in horizontal anymore.

Comment: For mobile you may show the divs vertically. This means that you add @media query for mobile and change the settings.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, I asked you this thing because I'm trying to understand well the use of inline, block and inline-block :D

Comment: Ok, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: And if I want to add more identical line below this line (inside to the "block1"), I want to add another "content-block-2". Do I have to use the clear property? If I just add only the div, the second line is confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146954/discussion-between-danielab67-and-matteo).

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto;` to the containing div.

Parent elements are never to expand to contain floated children. So to get them to do that, you need to tell the parent that elements overflowing the container should automatically expand to contain them.

There are other methods to do this but this is the simplest. Search for "clearing floats"

Answer (score 0):

Using the Floats make the parent element collapse its height. To retain its height we need to clear the floats. So the best way is to add the clearfix element bottom of the floating elements.

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="block1">
  <div class="head-block-1">
    Best Selling Tickets
  </div>

  <div class="content-block-1">
    <div>
      <span class="data-block-1 img-block">
      <img src="/nutickets2/images/circle.png" height="55px">
      </span>
      <span class="data-block-1">
        <span>Adult - General</span><span><br>TEST TEST</span>
      </span>
      <span class="data-block-1">
        <span>50 sold since Jan 17</span>
        <span><br>20% more sold than last period</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block1 {
    width: 96%;
    height: 96%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #d1d1d1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.head-block-1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.content-block-1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    padding: 15px;
}
.clearfix
{
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.data-block-1 {
    width: 33%; 
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: And what does that do? Teach him how to fish. Don't just throw him a fish.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of floats. A flexbox simplifies the layouts and floats can be avoided.

```css
.block1 {
  width: 96%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #d1d1d1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.content-block-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.head-block-1 {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <div class="head-block-1">
    Best Selling Tickets
  </div>
  <div class="content-block-1">
    <span>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/55/bda603">
    </span>
    <span>Adult - General<br>TEST TEST
    </span>
    <span>50 sold since Jan 17<br>20% more sold than last period
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```